# Gmapping localization problem Turtlebot

Tags: navigation, turtlebot2, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am actually experimenting the gmapping package with the Turtlebot2. To create the map I am using a Hokuyo Laser and not the Kinect.

Everything works fine at the beginning, but at one point the Turtlebot has a localization problem. It's at the right place and one second later it moves several meters away in the map in rviz.
Is seems that at the same time I have this error message :
*[ERROR] [1363969960.064180503]: Transform from base_link to odom failed*
And after that the map is not precise anymore.

Do you know what I can do to solve that ?
How can this transform fail ? Why ?

Thanks for help,
Caroline

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58955/gmapping-localization-problem-turtlebot/) by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-03-22

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-03-29**:
should not! Did you experience that problems in cases other than map building?

**Comment by [shiloh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5051/shiloh/) on 2013-06-04**:
I'm seeing the same problem.  My setup is a Turtlebot1 (Create base) with Hokuyo but no Kinect, running Groovy.  The symptoms I'm seeing are exactly the same on both map-building and navigating in a static map.  Has anyone ever found a solution?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-06-04**:
Yes, looks the same problem. I'll tackle it in shiloh's question

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-11-12**:
@jorge please post the link to that question or your answer here. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to suggest a few measures which you should try out once:

1. One of the possible problems could be stalling of CPU cycles,
   Firstly, check the CPU processing of your laptop while gmapping package is running on turtlebot and simultaneously observe the turtlebot movement in rviz.
   If you observe CPU cycle striking near 100% or if rviz hangs or goes offline for short time interval every time the turtlebot moves, then one of possible solution is to increase the parameter value of "map_update_interval" in gmapping package to around 25-30.
2. If still the problem exists, the other solution is increase the the parameter value "maxUrange" in gmapping package according to the environment. According to my experience if your room is about 10m by 5m , then your range shoud lie around 5m atleast.

This worked out for me.

---

Originally posted by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) with karma: 311 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1